# Google maps getdirections api - polyline

Tags: java, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I am using [Google maps getDirections api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/). I use JSON type webservice to get the info from Google webservice. [Here is the sample](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON) JSON output from webservice. I am using Java to process the result. I don't know how to read the polyline data. I have given a snippet of polyline object below.

```js
"polyline": {
   "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P",
   "levels": "B?B"
},
```

The documentation says that

> Polyline contains an object holding an array of encoded points and levels that represent an approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions.

How to read the encoded data in Java. **I need to decode both points and levels**. A sample Java code snippet could help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://www.geekyblogger.com/2010/12/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is Google's documentation of the [encoded polyline](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Encoding) format. If you want to display the directions in a browser then that is probably sufficient.
If you do need the results in Java then here is a version of the [decoder](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/). I've never used it but it looks correct and resilient.